# Mac Texshop "autofilling"

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

I couldn't find it anywhere here, but sorry in advance if this is a repeated question.

When using Texshop on my Mac, when I do the following...

1. Type out  `f(x) = 2x + 3`
2. highlight `f(x) = 2x + 3`
3. type `$`

It will do a "autofill" and surround my `f(x) = 2x + 3` with `$`'s, resulting in `$f(x) = 2x+3$`.

This is absolutely driving me mad. It does similarly with quotations, parentheses, and other similar commands. Where can I disable this feature?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need a $ at the beginning and another $ at the end. So why do you want to type $ twice instead of once?

Comment: I realize I need both $'s at either end. I just don't like this feature and would like to disable. 

For example, if I do the following:

1. Type out $f(x) = 2x + 3$
2. Realize I don't want this and highlight $f(x) = 2x + 3$
3. type $

The result is $$f(x) = 2x + 3$$, where all I wanted to do was delete/replace it all with just a single $.

Comment: Select the text and hit DELETE before `$`. It's easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach works with version 4.24 of TeXshop. (It may work with earlier versions as well, but I have no way of testing this conjecture.)

- Open TeXShop
- From the top ribbon, select "TeXShop" -> "Preferences..."
- Select the "Editor" tab. You should be looking at something like this:

[image]

- Unselect the "Editor Can Add Brackets" box in the left-hand column
- Click on "OK" in the bottom right hand corner

Happy TeXShopping!

Of course, with this approach, if you now highlight `f(x) = 2x + 3` and then type `$`, the highlighted material will be wiped out and replaced with `$`. Or, if you highlight `f(x) = 2x + 3` and type `(`, the highlighted material will be wiped out and replaced with `(`. In contrast, if the "Editor Can Add Brackets" box were checked, TeXshop would *not* wipe out the highlighted material and, instead, surround it with matching `$` symbols, matching parentheses, etc.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I don't like auto-filling features.